# How to find fastest mirror link during every installation

Tags: networking, software-installation, internet, vpn

This is the problem:
sometimes I connected to internet via VPN (this VPN server could be in countries like USA, UK and etc)
sometimes I connected to internet without VPN.
When I connected  to internet via VPN the fastest mirrror link that I  can use it is from that country servers.
But when I connected to internet without VPN, the fastest mirror links are belong to my country (because there is  no VPN)

This solution can solve this problem if:
when I connected to Internet and I want to install an app,an script a little time before installation of each package find  the fastest mirror link.

At this time no matter that I connected with VPN or without it

How I can solve this problem  in action?

Comment: There is a section in the software updater to find fastest mirror, but unless you change the speed from mirrors, say from dial up to more than 10GB/s, do not think it would make much difference.  You can probably download what you want, in the time it takes to find and change  mirrors.

Comment: correct,thank you for your response